# Are indexed columns with NULL values ignored by the cost-based optimizer?

Tags: informix

I have a voter table with ~640M rows that has a DateOfDeath DATE column which is indexed.

~410M of the rows have NULL values in DateOfDeath column because these voters are still alive.

If I do a query to select all rows with DateOfDeath between "01012015" and "12312015", will the optimizer bypass all rows that have NULL values in DateOfDeath, without having to do a full table scan?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the query, but the query would probably use the index on DateOfDeath and would certainly not need to scan the range of the index where the DateOfDeath is NULL in order to answer that query.  You'd need to be sure you've run UPDATE STATISTICS recently if your version of Informix is older than about 11.50.

Comment: SE uses C-ISAM B+tree, whereas IDS uses RSAM (also B+tree?). So are node entries not inserted in the index file for indexed columns with NULL values?

Comment: Yes, entries are inserted for NULLs (in both SE and IDS), but a search wouldn't need to do a full index scan, much less a full table scan, to select the relevant records given a search for non-NULL DateOfDeath values in a specified range.

Comment: Ok thanks. Indexes on a table with ~640M rows have more than 8 node levels. As DateOfDeath column is updated from NULL to non-NULL, and new rows are inserted, at what point do indexes become stale requiring re-indexing?

Comment: Reindexing?  Never?  When you delete large numbers of rows?  Indexes are designed/intended to stay functional over extended periods of time and extensive activity.  If you have the data in the table organized so they are in order of DateOfDeath, then you may want to periodically rebuild the table by doing ALTER INDEX idxname TO NOT CLUSTER and then ALTER INDEX idxname TO CLUSTER, but it won't often be truly necessary. OTOH, if you don't normally access the table in order of DateOfDeath, you won't want to cluster the index on that column. If DateOfBirth is more frequently used, cluster on that.

Comment: The cluster index is on (CustomerLastNames,CustomerFirstNames) because users query on those columns, but users sometimes query by DateOfBirth, or DateOfDeath. IIRC, one of the improvements made to indexing in SE 4.10 was that NULL values are entirely skipped when scanning index tables for non NULL values to improve performance.

Comment: you also stated " You'd need to be sure you've run UPDATE STATISTICS recently if your version of Informix is older than about 11.50.". Does this mean newer IDS versions automatically maintain table statistics without having to exec update statistics?

Comment: @FrankR. You should be able to find AUS or 'automatic update statistics' in the manuals — for example, [Informix 12.10 Knowledge Centre](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/aus%20automatic%20update%20statistics?scope=SSGU8G_12.1.0). It should tell you all about it. The short version is "yes, more or less".